# How to calculate a ratio for each month in a year and attach 12 ratio columns (will be 12 columns) to the origianl dataset in R?

Tags: r

My dataset has 3000 observations (rows) and 24 variables (columns). First 12 (column 1 to 12) variables are price value from January to December in a year. The remaining 12 variables (column 13 to 24) are rent value from January to December in the same year. I would like to caculate the price/rent for each month and add the 12 new ratios columns to the end of my origianl dataset. How can I do this in R?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to ask a good question regarding R and edit the post accordingly. Particularly, please include the output of ``dput(head(data))`` in your original post rather than describing your dataset, since it will make it much easier for people to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do :

```
df[paste0('ratio', 1:12)] <- df[1:12]/df[13:24]
```

This will create 12 new columns called `ratio1`, `ratio2` ... `ratio12`. where `ratio1` is column1/column13 `ratio2` is column2/column14 and so on.